# how to delete the cells if it contains zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet which contains 9 columns and n rows. In this from column 2 to 9 the values are either 0 or 1. Column 1 will contain name of a person. Now I have to remove the cell which contains 0 and bring the cells which contains 1 consecutively next to name. Please help me to write a macro for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro, just follow these steps:

1. Select columns 2 to 9.
2. Use Find/Replace (Ctrl-H) to replace 0 with nothing (Find: 0, Replace With: (blank), click Replace All). This should leave you with only 1's.
3. Use GoTo (Ctrl-G), click Special, select blanks, Click OK. You should now have all blank cells selected.
4. Right click on any of the selected cells and click Delete...
5. Choose to Shift Cells Left then click OK

If you really want it as a macro, then just record the steps you perform using the Macro Recorder. Search for help on recording macros in Excel.

Comment: This does not work if the contents of the cell is a formula that evaluates to exactly zero.  e.g.  =A1*0.   How can I clear contents based on the value contained in the cell?

Comment: Instead, open Find (Ctrl-F). Find What = 0. Click on "Options >>" and change "Look In" to "Values". Click Find All. Then press Ctrl-A to select all found cells. Close the Find Window. Then you can clear or delete the cells.

Comment: Thank you!  One detail:  I also needed to check "Match entire cell contents".   Without that, every cell that contains a "0" is selected.   E.g., a cell containing a number "10", or a cell that contains a formula that evaluates to "10" are selected.